# what connection type is ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIMAX?

Tags: java, android

Iam asking the connection types from am android device, but I have no idea what type is wimax.

```
ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo[] networkInfos = conMgr.getAllNetworkInfo();
if (networkInfos != null) {
  for (NetworkInfo networkInfo : networkInfos) {
     if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIMAX){
          // what type is this? 2G, 4G?. It is not wi-fi, nor bluetooth
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**WiMAX** is a wireless technology put forth by the [WiMAX Forum](http://www.wimaxforum.org/) that is one of the technologies that is being used for **4G networks**.
It can be used in both point to point and the typical WAN type configurations that are also used by 2G and 3G mobile network carriers.
 
Its formal name is IEEE standard 802.16.
Sprint owns a WiMAX based network that is marketed under the name XOHM, though that will eventually be merged with Clearwire's network and sold under the Clearwire name.
 LTE is a competing technology that has the support of far more carriers worldwide.

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) to understand connectivity manager

Answer (score -1):

public static final int TYPE_WIMAX

Added in API level 8
The WiMAX data connection. When active, all data traffic will use this network type's interface by default (it has a default route).

Constant Value: 6 (0x00000006)

Comment: this not add anything more than the documentation which  Ihave readed it, you can link it as Comment, this is not a response